# Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT when expo build:ios

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting an Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT error when I try to build my ios app using expo. The app is a new expo init project just for testing purposes.

This is the full error show in my console:

```
Reason: Unknown reason, raw: {"type":"Encoding::CompatibilityError","message":"Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT","backtrace":["/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:133:in `normalize'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/unicode_normalize.rb:38:in `unicode_normalize'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/babosa-1.0.2/lib/babosa/utf8/dumb_proxy.rb:26:in `normalize_utf8'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/babosa-1.0.2/lib/babosa/identifier.rb:248:in `normalize_utf8!'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/babosa-1.0.2/lib/babosa/identifier.rb:68:in `initialize'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/babosa-1.0.2/lib/babosa.rb:9:in `new'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/babosa-1.0.2/lib/babosa.rb:9:in `to_identifier'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.117.1/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/portal_client.rb:178:in `valid_name_for'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.117.1/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/portal_client.rb:211:in `create_app!'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.117.1/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/app.rb:102:in `create!'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/app/ensure_app_exists.rb:23:in `ensure_app_exists'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/app/ensure_app_exists.rb:42:in `block in <main>'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/app/funcs.rb:4:in `with_captured_stderr'","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.9.11-osx/lib/app/ensure_app_exists.rb:38:in `<main>'"]}
```

Im using a mac (10.13.6) and ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-darwin17].

My apple ID credentials are working fine (I tried with two different accounts, same error).

Is anyone facing this issue?